# Right-click on a NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, contextmenu, right-click, nsstatusitem, nsevent

I have a `NSStatusItem` and I want to popup a menu by rightclicking the item. I subclassed a NSView and overwrote the `- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event` method. I also implemented `- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event` for looking at the modifierflags. My problem is, that the view does not recieve the `NSRightMouseDown`-Event. And I don't know why? Any ideas how to get this event? Naturally I added the custom view to the statusitem.

**- UPDATE -**
Additional information: I have added a NSImageView to my custom view's subviews.

**- UPDATE 2 -**
Additional information: It conforms to the `NSMenuDelegate` protocol.

Comment: I am puzzled. I just built a short test app, and was able to receive both `mouseDown` and `rightMouseDown` events. Maybe you could give us more information on the design of your `NSView` subclass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa: Right Click NSStatusItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565820/cocoa-right-click-nsstatusitem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. The problem was the `NSImageView`. I subclassed it and now I redirect all `mouseDown` and `rigthMouseDown` events to its superview (my custom view).