# How to open a text a in my os x app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I am building an os x application in which i want to open text anywhere in the system and my app should search for the corresponding word in the dictionary and show the output.

From the below picture you can see that, i want to my app in that services area just like Todoist and Twitter. And also you can see that it open this sheet, when i select a text and right clicked on it. So what should i do in order to get it.?

Also please tell me , how should i perform an action in application:openurl for this scenario, Thanks in advance.

[image: Like this]

Comment: I think you have to look into using plugins or app extensions to do this.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565820/cocoa-right-click-nsstatusitem

Comment: Any news about how to open text in an app?

Comment: @cocoseis not yet, I forgot to take a look on to that. Will do